# Why this Angular 4 directive doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

**Context:** I am trying to create a directive for input type number, that doesn't allow user to type any character other than numbers in the input, I think I am not far but the directive doesn't behave like expected.

**Expected behavior :** when user types number it's OK, the numbers are kept in the input, but if he types letters the letters are automatically erased and only the numbers are kept.

**Current behavior :** on Firefox and Safari (on Chrome it works well) when user types numbers it's OK but as soon as he types a letter all the input's content get deleted, even the number previously typed.

**Reproduction scenario :** I have [stackblitzed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3o6y5) the case, you can start typing numbers in the input it's OK and then when you type letters, the input get deleted.

**The code :**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { DefaultValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=number]',
  host: {
    '(input)': 'onInput($event.target.value)'
  },
})

export class NumberDirective extends DefaultValueAccessor {

  constructor(renderer: Renderer2, elementRef: ElementRef) { super(renderer, elementRef, false); }

  onInput(value: any): void {
    const transformed = this.transformValue(value);
    super.writeValue(transformed);
    this.onChange(transformed);
  }

  private transformValue(value: any): any {
    return value.replace(/[^0-9|\s]+/g, '');
  }
}
```

**Questions :**

1. How can I get this directive to work?
2. My IDE is complaining because using host metadata doesn't respect the [style guide Style 06-03](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-06-03) and I should instead use HostListener/HostBinding decorators . You would be like my superhero if you help me to use HostListener with my directive because I don't know how to use HostListener at all.

Comment: On your stackblitzed everythig works. Can type numbers but no letters, no number get deleted.

Comment: @Doomenik : have you tried with Firefox? Which version? I am on firefox mac version 55.0.3 64 bits and it doesn't work for me, when I type letters previous numbers get deleted.

Comment: I´m on chrome, the html5 tag number already doesnt allow nearly all letters expect a few like `e` . And yes if I type that one at the end of the number, the previous one get deleted. If you type it between it works as you want. I´m using the build in validators so I´m sry but cant help you in this case. I just can tell you it doesn´t provide the correct value to the `ònInput`function if you type a letter as last character